# How can I create this icon using pathfinder tool in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I am facing difficulties creating this icon (for learning purposes). I tried to create this with the pathfinder tool but I am not getting the desired result. How can I create this?

[image: This is the icon-]

Comment: I really do not see Pathfinder being the simplest tool to create this. Far simpler with the pen tool or maybe create circles and delete certain parts of them and then connect where wanted with the line tool. You can use this drawing as a template.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use Pathfinder here either.. but **Shape Builder** will help...

Simple line a circle...

[image]

Duplicate circle and align things...

[image]

Delete half of each circle...

[image]

Join the 3 pieces...

[image]

Reflect Horizontally as a *copy*, then reflect vertically to get the circles on the other side of the line.

[image]

Join these two pieces, then copy the entire thing to the right...

[image]

Using the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) delete the bottom circles on the right and with the **Pen Tool** add a horizontal line....

[image]

Align the bottom horizontal to the circle on the left. Then draw simple horizontal paths across areas that are currently open but need to be closed....

[image]

Select all and use the **Shape Builder Tool** to combine areas into closed shapes...

[image]

Because Shape Builder had some trouble with a few of the line extensions, I used the **Direct Selection Tool** to zoom in and remove those remnants...

[image]

Select all, set the stroke to black and the fill to white...

[image]

You can then use the Direct Selection tool to select half the anchors and adjust the width if desired...

[image]